# Clang: changing the inline asm printer format

Tags: clang, llvm, inline-assembly, riscv

I am trying to change the format of the inline asm printer of Clang.
The instruction I am trying to write with inline assembler is my original instruction.
Let's say the instruction name is 'abc', and it requires 3 operands(1 output, 2 inputs).
in C code, it is written like this:

```
int abc(int data, int addr)
{
    int res;

    asm volatile("abc %2, %1, %0" : "=r"(res) : "r"(addr), "r"(data));

    return res;
}
```

when I compile with the command below,

```
clang -c --sysroot=riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu main.c -S --target=riscv32 -march=rv32imf -mabi=ilp32f
```

the output of the inline asm part in main.s will look like this.

```
abc    a0 a0 a1
```

the other instructions has commas between operands, but the instruction inserted with inline assembler has no commas.
I want it to look like below

```
abc    a0, a0, a1
```

which file of clang source should I modify to make insert commas between operands?

Thank you in advance.

Now, I am using a python script that I wrote to insert commas in the assembly that was inserted by inline assembler.

Comment: With clang 15.0.7 (configured with default Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu on my Linux desktop), after fixing your [mcve] to use a valid RISC-V instruction (`add` not `abc`), your command produced `add     a1, a0, a0` in the asm output (bracketed by `#APP` and `#NO_APP`), using commas the same as when printing compiler-generated instructions.  (With or without `-o- | less` to print asm to stdout instead of a file.)  What clang version are you using, configured how?